# (Count on today) minus (count on previous day) for 1 Month duration

Tags: mysql, sql

How to query the sum of today count that need to be subtracted with sum of previous day count, daily for duration of one month.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT member_profile.memberProfileNumber)
FROM member_profile
LEFT JOIN member_token
ON member_profile.id = member_token.memberProfileId
WHERE member_profile.memberProfileNumber LIKE 'MM%';
```

I have two tables and columns as below:

**Table member_profile**

```
memberProfileNumber
id
```

**Table member_token**

```
memberProfileId
createdAt
```

Expected result:

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: You would get a quicker answer (and possibly more suitable) if you added sample data and expected output as text to the question. Otherwise I would have to make it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can do the aggregation in a subquery, and then use `LAG(...) OVER(...)` in the outer query to bring in the value from the previous day, like:

```
SELECT 
    createdAtDay,
    cnt,
    cnt - LAG(cnt) OVER(ORDER BY createdAtDay) cnt_diff
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(mt.createdAt) createdAtDay, COUNT(DISTINCT mf.memberProfileNumber) cnt
    FROM member_profile mf
    INNER JOIN member_token mt 
        ON mf.id = mt.memberProfileId 
        AND mt.createdAt >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    WHERE mf.memberProfileNumber LIKE 'MM%' AND 
    GROUP BY DATE(createdAt)
) x
```

NB1: I believe that `LEFT JOIN member_token` should be `INNER JOIN member_token`, since column `member_token.createdAt` is used to aggregate the results.

NB2: the subquery filters on tokens created within the last month.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with a simple join

```
drop table if exists member_profile,member_token;
create table member_profile
(memberProfileNumber int, id int);

create Table member_token
(memberProfileId  int,createdAt date);

insert into member_profile values
(1,1),(2,2),(3,3);
insert into member_token values
(1,'2019-01-01'),(1,'2019-01-01'),
(2,'2019-01-01'),(3,'2019-01-01'),
(1,'2019-01-02'),(2,'2019-01-02'),
(1,'2019-01-03'),(3,'2019-01-03');

select mt.createdat,count(distinct memberprofileid) todayobs,
        y.createdat yesterdaydate,
         max(yesterdayobs) yesterdayobs,
         ifnull(count(distinct memberprofileid),0) -  ifnull(max(yesterdayobs),0) changeonday
from member_token mt
left join
(select createdat,count(distinct memberprofileid) yesterdayobs
    from member_token mt1 
         group by createdat
         ) y on y.createdat = date_sub(mt.createdat, interval 1 day)
group by mt.createdat;

+------------+----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
| createdat  | todayobs | yesterdaydate | yesterdayobs | changeonday |
+------------+----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2019-01-01 |        3 | NULL          |         NULL |           3 |
| 2019-01-02 |        2 | 2019-01-01    |            3 |          -1 |
| 2019-01-03 |        2 | 2019-01-02    |            2 |           0 |
+------------+----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note 1) I have not qualified the month 2) The solution supposes there is an entry for every day in the member_token table 3) I didn't see the relevance of the member_profile table.

Comment: The member profile table is to use conditions in which to count memberprofilenumber that met the condition. I will test this query. Thanks :)